# Extracting structured data from web page using JSOUP and Coldfusion

Tags: json, web-scraping, coldfusion, jsoup

I need to extract structured data for recipes from a website using JSOUP (or any other effective method) using Coldfusion.

The data is structure as follows: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/recipe

I need to get the JSON from the page and parse it into useable variables.

I have tried a number of different options without success. I do not know JSOUP and will appreciate your help.

The data looks like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Recipe",
  "name": "Party Coffee Cake",
  "image": [
    "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
    "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
  ],
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Mary Stone"
  },
  "datePublished": "2018-03-10",
  "description": "This coffee cake is awesome and perfect for parties.",
  "prepTime": "PT20M",
  "cookTime": "PT30M",
  "totalTime": "PT50M",
  "keywords": "cake for a party, coffee",
  "recipeYield": "10",
  "recipeCategory": "Dessert",
  "recipeCuisine": "American",
  "nutrition": {
    "@type": "NutritionInformation",
    "calories": "270 calories"
  },
  "recipeIngredient": [
    "2 cups of flour",
    "3/4 cup white sugar",
    "2 teaspoons baking powder",
    "1/2 teaspoon salt",
    "1/2 cup butter",
    "2 eggs",
    "3/4 cup milk"
    ],
  "recipeInstructions": [
    {
      "@type": "HowToStep",
      "name": "Preheat",
      "text": "Preheat the oven to 350 degrees F. Grease and flour a 9x9 inch pan.",
      "url": "https://example.com/party-coffee-cake#step1",
      "image": "https://example.com/photos/party-coffee-cake/step1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "@type": "HowToStep",
      "name": "Mix dry ingredients",
      "text": "In a large bowl, combine flour, sugar, baking powder, and salt.",
      "url": "https://example.com/party-coffee-cake#step2",
      "image": "https://example.com/photos/party-coffee-cake/step2.jpg"
    },
    {
      "@type": "HowToStep",
      "name": "Add wet ingredients",
      "text": "Mix in the butter, eggs, and milk.",
      "url": "https://example.com/party-coffee-cake#step3",
      "image": "https://example.com/photos/party-coffee-cake/step3.jpg"
    },
    {
      "@type": "HowToStep",
      "name": "Spread into pan",
      "text": "Spread into the prepared pan.",
      "url": "https://example.com/party-coffee-cake#step4",
      "image": "https://example.com/photos/party-coffee-cake/step4.jpg"
    },
    {
      "@type": "HowToStep",
      "name": "Bake",
      "text": "Bake for 30 to 35 minutes, or until firm.",
      "url": "https://example.com/party-coffee-cake#step5",
      "image": "https://example.com/photos/party-coffee-cake/step5.jpg"
    },
    {
      "@type": "HowToStep",
      "name": "Enjoy",
      "text": "Allow to cool and enjoy.",
      "url": "https://example.com/party-coffee-cake#step6",
      "image": "https://example.com/photos/party-coffee-cake/step6.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "ratingValue": "5",
    "ratingCount": "18"
  },
  "video": {
    "@type": "VideoObject",
    "name": "How to make a Party Coffee Cake",
    "description": "This is how you make a Party Coffee Cake.",
    "thumbnailUrl": [
      "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
      "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
      "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
     ],
    "contentUrl": "http://www.example.com/video123.mp4",
    "embedUrl": "http://www.example.com/videoplayer?video=123",
    "uploadDate": "2018-02-05T08:00:00+08:00",
    "duration": "PT1M33S",
    "interactionStatistic": {
      "@type": "InteractionCounter",
      "interactionType": { "@type": "WatchAction" },
      "userInteractionCount": 2347
    },
    "expires": "2019-02-05T08:00:00+08:00"
  }
}
</script>
```

I have tried the following:

```
<cfset source = "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/216319/homemade-sweet-italian-sausage-mild-or-hot/">

<cfhttp method="get" url="#source#" result="theresult" useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.391.0 Safari/533.7"> 
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="gzip,deflate,sdch" >
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Proxy-Connection" value="keep-alive" >
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Language" value="en-US,en;q=0.8">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Charset" value="ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3">
<cfhttpparam type="cookie" name="some-cookie" value="1">
</cfhttp>
```

With he above I get the web page.

I then try to extract the JSON:

```
<cfscript>
// Create the jsoup object
Jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
// HTML string
html = "#theresult.filecontent#";
// Parse the string
document = Jsoup.parse(html);
// Extract content
title = document.title();
tags = document.select("script[type=application/ld+json]"); 
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#tags#">
<cfloop index="e" array="#tags#">
<cfoutput>
    #e.attr("content")#<br>
</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

But I get nothing returned.

Comment: What have you tried?? Provide some examples of your code first.

Comment: Updated my question with my attempt.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using regex instead?  Have you tried outputting tags.toString()?

Comment: The best way to extract the JSON from your result is to isolate the text between the opening and closing `<script>` tags and from that result use `deserializeJSON()` to assign it into a CF object.  That makes it very easy to access all the variable values you want to use from the resultant structure.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <script type="application/ld+json">[
>     {
>       "@context": "http://schema.org",
>       "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
>        ...
>     }
> </script>
> ```

The `<script>` tag doesn't have an attribute named `"content"` (only one named `"type"`). To retrieve the tag contents (or its inner html) use the [Element.html()](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#html(java.lang.String)) method. Then deserialize the returned contents as json:

```
<cfscript>
   Jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");
   document = Jsoup.parse( theResult.fileContent );
   tag = document.select("script[type=application/ld+json]").first(); 
   if (isJSON(tag.html())) {
       contents = deserializeJSON( tag.html() );
       writeDump(contents);
   }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you help me to output the "contents"? 

I have tried this:

     <cfloop array="#contents#" index="prop">
        <cfoutput>
            #prop.recipeIngredient#<br>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfloop>

And Im getting an error that "recipeIngredient is undefined in PROP"